# Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, anyobject

I have some problems with my Swift project. I am making an app where you can be notified about when you need to take your medicine.

Here is the file where the error code is generated:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TodoList {
class var sharedInstance : TodoList {
    struct Static {
        static let instance : TodoList = TodoList()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

private let ITEMS_KEY = "todoItems"

func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
    let todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:]
    let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)
    return items.map({TodoItem(deadline: $0["deadline"] as! NSDate, title: $0["title"] as! String, gentag: $0 ["gentag"] as! RepeatInterval, UUID: $0["UUID"] as! String)}).sort({(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
        (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .OrderedAscending)
    })
}

func addItem(item: TodoItem) {
    // persist a representation of this todo item in NSUserDefaults
    var todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? Dictionary() // if todoItems hasn't been set in user defaults, initialize todoDictionary to an empty dictionary using nil-coalescing operator (??)
    todoDictionary[item.UUID] = ["deadline": item.deadline, "title": item.title, "gentag": item.gentag.toCalendarUnit(), "UUID": item.UUID] // store NSData representation of todo item in dictionary with UUID as key
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todoDictionary, forKey: ITEMS_KEY) // save/overwrite todo item list

    // create a corresponding local notification
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Hej \"\(item.title)\"Test, husk at tage din medicin: \"\(item.title)\"" // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.alertAction = "Skub for at tage medicin" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
    notification.fireDate = item.deadline // todo item due date (when notification will be fired)
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
    notification.userInfo = ["title": item.title, "UUID": item.UUID] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later
    notification.repeatInterval = item.gentag.toCalendarUnit()



    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}

func removeItem(item: TodoItem) {
    for notification in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications as [UILocalNotification]! { // loop through notifications...
        if (notification.userInfo!["UUID"] as! String == item.UUID) { // ...and cancel the notification that corresponds to this TodoItem instance (matched by UUID)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification) // there should be a maximum of one match on UUID
            break
        }
    }

    if var todoItems = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) {
        todoItems.removeValueForKey(item.UUID)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todoItems, forKey: ITEMS_KEY) // save/overwrite todo item list
    }
}
```

Here is the line which generates the error:

```
 todoDictionary[item.UUID] = ["deadline": item.deadline, "title": item.title, "gentag": item.gentag.toCalendarUnit(), "UUID": item.UUID] // store NSData representation of todo item in dictionary with UUID as key
```

Here is the error text:

> Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Here is my ToDoItem class

```
import Foundation

struct TodoItem {
    var title: String
    var deadline: NSDate
    var gentag: RepeatInterval
    var UUID: String

   init(deadline: NSDate, title: String, gentag: RepeatInterval, UUID: String) {
        self.deadline = deadline
        self.title = title
        self.gentag = gentag
        self.UUID = UUID
    }

    var isOverdue: Bool {
        return (NSDate().compare(self.deadline) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending) // deadline is earlier than current date
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your ToDoItem class?

Comment: I have updated my question @impression7vx

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your trouble ....

```
import Foundation

struct S {
    var i = 1
    var b = true
    var c = 1.0
    var id = "XYZ-ID"
}

var d = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("dummy_key") ?? [:]
let s = S()
d[s.id] = ["i":s.i, "b":s.b, "c":s.c]


print(d)
/*
 ["XYZ-ID": {
 b = 1;
 c = 1;
 i = 1;
 }]
*/
```

The error you receive means, that swift can't create AnyObject on the right side of the assignment. Check it separately, most likely it is  because RepeatInterval doesn't have bridged Foundation counterpart.